# Multiple iterations with multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I rewrote method, which initially was for only one thread, to work with many threads. Now, this method accepts two concurrent collections: `ConcurrentBag`, which was `List`, and `ConcurrentQueue`, which was `Queue`.

The purpose is to match two titles from both  collection and make some logic, which is simple value assignment in `ConcurrentBag` items. I know, for sure, that all symbols in `ConcurrentBag` are in `ConcurrentQueue`.

When I wrote this for multi threads, it occured that some of titles do not match (~20%), which did not happen when there was on thread. Only during debugging I can match these titles and then values are assigned. There has to be some problem with iterating these two collections. Maybe in the same time many threads reads values from the same item, but only reading should not be problem?

Below code:

```
public void UpdateWithPercent(ref ConcurrentBag<Book> refList, ConcurrentQueue<Book> list)
{
    var size = list.Count;
    int numProcs = Environment.ProcessorCount;
    var divider = CalculatBiggestDivider(size);
    var nextIteration = 0;
    var remainingWork = numProcs;
    var internalRefList = refList;
    using (ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numProcs; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
            {
                IEnumerable<Book> partialList;
                while (-(nextIteration - Interlocked.Add(ref nextIteration, (partialList = DequeueChunk(list, divider)).Count()))> 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in partialList)
                    {
                        foreach (var x in internalRefList)
                        {
                            if (x.Title == item.Title)
                            {
                                x.Orders += item.Orders;
                                break;
                            }
                        };
                    }
                }

                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref remainingWork) == 0)
                {
                    mre.Set();
                }
            });
        }

        mre.WaitOne();
    }

    refList = internalRefList;
}

private int CalculatBiggestDivider(int count)
{
    var divider = 1;
    for (int i = 30; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (count % i == 0)
        {
            divider = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return divider;
}

private IEnumerable<T> DequeueChunk<T>(ConcurrentQueue<T> queue, int chunkSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < chunkSize && queue.Count > 0; i++)
    {
        T item;
        bool success = queue.TryDequeue(out item);
        if (!success)
        {
            i = chunkSize;
            continue;
        }
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the initial purpose to write it with `ConcurrentBag` and `ConcurrentQueue`? Is it a *bad performance* (nested `foreach` loops)? If so, why not turn `refList` into `Dictionary<string, Book>` or `HashSet<string>` and thus get rid of inner `foreach`?

Comment: Could you, please, describe the logic behind the routine in *plain words*? I doubt if multithreading will be much faster; however, turning time complexity from `O(N * M)` (nested loops) to `O(N + M)` (`Hashset`/`Dictionary` within single `foreach`) is promising.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko, Yes, you have right that nestedloops are not best for performance. Actually, using Dictionary would be great benefit. I did not think about it. Rewriting it to multithreads was only for learining purposes. I would like to know what does not work here.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko, I used here concurrentcollection because of many threads.

Comment: From what I understand, different threads can access different keys in simple ditcionary or different items of list. They can not access the same key at the same time for known reasons. To protect we can use lock or concurrent collections.

Comment: threads can *read* same keys, values, etc. (`int x = dict[someKey];` is OK) it's *writing* which should we protect

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko, yes, by access I meant writting. From what I understand, different threads can write different keys in simple ditcionary or different items of list. They can not write the same key at the same time for known reasons. To protect we can use lock or concurrent collections.

Comment: unfortunately, no. `Dictionary<K, V>` and `List<T>` both want *exlusive access* when modifing (add/edit/remove) - when modifing no other thread must not read or write any data from these collections.

Comment: ok, so only concurrentQueue and concurrentBad allow modifing different keys in collection at the same time. It is called fine grained locking.

Comment: yes, `Concurrent` collections (`ConcurrentBag`, `ConcurrentQueue`, `ConcurrentDictionary`) use *locking* when it's *necessary* ( that's why it's *fine grained*)

Comment: `while (-(nextIteration - Interlocked.Add(ref nextIteration, (partialList = DequeueChunk(list, divider)).Count()))> 0)` this is a mind boggling piece of code. Hard to understand and reason about its correctness.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias, It only check if items exist in queue, retrieve them, assign to partialList and adding count to nextIteration. It is litte complicated, but it works :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I decided to resign from nestedloops and used `ConcurrentDictionary`. Now it works.

```
public void UpdateWithPercent(ref ConcurrentDictionary<string, Book> refList, List<Book> list, int ticker, int maxTimes)
{
    var size = list.Count;
    int numProcs = Environment.ProcessorCount;
    var divider = CalculatBiggestDivider(size);
    var nextIteration = 0;
    var remainingWork = numProcs;
    var internalRefList = refList;
    using (ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numProcs; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
            {
                int index = 0;
                while ((index = Interlocked.Add(ref nextIteration, divider) - divider) < size)
                {
                    foreach (var item in list.GetRange(index, divider))
                    {
                        Book x;
                        if (internalRefList.TryGetValue(item.Title, out x))
                        {
                                x.Orders += item.Orders;
                        }
                    };
                }

                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref remainingWork) == 0)
                {
                    mre.Set();
                }
            });
        }

        mre.WaitOne();
    }

    refList = internalRefList;
}
```

Comment: This problem doesn't really need a multithreading solution. In case it needed one, it would be much better to let the framework do the partitioning and the thread management by using the [`Parallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel) class.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias, I know about it, but I wanted to this without Parallel.

Comment: If you feel the need to use the `ManualResetEvent` class and the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` method in application code, then you are doing something wrong. These are low level tools, best suited for server components and libraries written and maintained by experts.